# How to pass Post parameter in WKWebview iOS

Tags: ios, swift, http, post, wkwebview

We are having a situation where we need to send Post parameters within WKWebView.

currently we are using UIWebView and need to migrate to WKWebView. As per Apple we cant send/add custom headers within WKWebView. Is there any alternate solution to get this done.
(Solution required in latest SWIFT version only)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wkWebview.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie)` method for custom headers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).